# iOS - Cell adjust constraints based on element visibility

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

Currently I've have a cell with some labels aligned within an image, but when there's no image to display, I wanna the labels to be aligned to the left of tableviewcell, I've tried set two constraints, one to superview, other to the image, but still doesn't work... It's possible to achieve this using only constraints priorities or something like that? Thanks a lot!
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could achieve that by setting a outlet to the image width constraint, and when there's no image to show, I set the constant of the constraint to zero. Although the element is not visible, it still occupies space in view design.

The code is something like this

```
        if let photoUrl = URL(string: photo) {
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            self.photoPostImageView.kf.setImage(with: photoUrl) { _ in
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        } else {
            self.photoPostImageView.isHidden    = true
            self.imageWidthConstraint.constant  = 0
        }
```